# Stirling numbers: Show that $S(n+1, r)=rS(n, r)+S(n, r-1)$.

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I know that the Stirling numbers of the second kind are the number of partitions of an $n$-set with $r$ non-empty parts, and that they can be denoted $S(n,r)$.

How would I then show $S(n+1, r)=rS(n, r)+S(n, r-1)$?
Could anyone provide me with any tips or hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose you have a partition of $n+1$ into $r$ parts. Order your parts in a line and locate the part that contains $n+1$ and take it out. There will be two options (Notice that perhaps you took out all elements of the part!!)

Comment: Woah that is brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: So now I am having some trouble ordering my parts. Would I want to start with $S(n+1, (n+1)-r)$?

Comment: Why do you think you should start with that? Ordering means putting them in a line, perhaps order them by minimal element of the part. When you put them in a line, is easier to see why would you have to multiply by $r.$

Comment: I think that I have it:
$S(n+1, r) = rS(n+1-1, r) + S(n+1-1, r-1) = rS(n, r) + S(n, r-1)$.
Am I getting closer?

Comment: Yes, you are done :).

Answer (score 1):

I see you already received an answer, but I wanted to share this video with you that covers the recursive formula you posted in a visual: https://youtu.be/hKYc9mwPJBA
Basically, you want to think about what happens when you add the additional element (+1) to the set of (n) elements to get (n + 1) elements; specificially, think about which former subdivisions of n into k still hold for n+1 into k.